# Help: Question About Functions

Tags: functions

Say we want to solve an equation like
$2e^{f(0)}-(f(0))^2=2$

I would like someone to explain why the following procedure is wrong.

I observe that $f(0)=0$ is a solution. 
If $f(0)=a$ is another solution then $f$ cannot be a function since for 1 "x" we get two "y". Therefore $f(0)=0$ is the only solution.

Comment: In fact $f(0)=0$ appears not to be a solution, since with $f(0)=0$, the left-hand side evaluates to $1$.

Comment: f(0)=0 isn't a solution. $e^0=1$ and $0^2=0$ so 1 does not equal 2.

Comment: Sorry. I meant to write $2*e^{f(0)}$

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions are two *different* functions. For each $x$, they each have exactly one $y$. Hence, there is no contradiction.